# WordPress, ACF Plugin: Why is a sub-field being saved as a main field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The issue is that I'm trying to create a Repeater field which has a single Text field within it. However, after clicking on update, the field is moved out of the Repeater field and placed as its neighbour. Researching, I only came up with issues where the field wasn't being saved at all, or the combined option names were too long if there was too much nesting of fields. I did increase the max_input_vars from the default 1000 to 3000, but nothing changes.

[Adding a new sub-field within the repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6bAQ.png)

[The state of the field group after updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEPKQ.png)

Some other info that might prove to be useful:

- WordPress version: 5.0.3
- ACF version: 5.6.3
- PHP version: 5.6

EDIT: To answer the comment below, and for future reference if you can't view the images, the Field Names are **landing_subtitles** and **subtitle** for the Repater field and Text sub-field, respectively.

Comment: Do the fields maybe have the same name? Sometimes that confuses acf!

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer on the same issue.

I updated my ACF Pro version from Version 5.6.10 to 5.8.0 and it works for me now.

**EDIT:**

Wordpress Version 5.0.3

PHP Version 7.2.7